# Why do we serialize java class and declaring a variable static won't serialize it?

Tags: java, serialization, static

A static class like Logger doesn't get serialized. Why ?

Comment: No idea what you are asking. If you want to make sure that a field isn't serialized, use the *transient* keyword.

Comment: If you serialise an instance of a class, the static field won't be serialised because it is not part of the instance. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: `static` fields are not part of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you mark a class as `Serializable`, you are requesting the Java runtime to serialize the **object** or **instance** of your class. This helps in converting the data in your object to a persistable format to store or to send via a strean.

On the other hand, `static` members do not belong to any class and fall outside the purview of Serialization. So, marking your class `Serializable` does not impact any of your class's `static` members.

When you deserialize an object, all its Class's `static` members will already be initialized in the other JVM when the class is loaded. So it doesn't make sense to send static field data as part of the serialized object.

See [this article](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/transient-vs-static-variable-java/) for more details.

Hope this helps!